# Is there a way to change android phone's mtu size?

Tags: android

My phone is having problem with sending data to the network. I think I have to change its MTU size to make it work.

Answer (score 6):

To change MTU settings you need a to root your phone. Search in foruns how to do it.
After that your need to install a terminal emulator and check what is your network interface
Run the command:

```
netcfg
```

and look at the IP address what is your desired device (wlan0, tiwlan0, etc)

then use this command

```
ifconfig $DEVICE mtu $MTU_VALUE
```

and substitute $DEVICE with device name and the desired MTU value in $MTU_VALUE

You can also see the value at this file:

```
cat /sys/class/net/$DEVICE/mtu
```

Comment: `error: SIOCSIFMTU (Operation not permitted)` <-- How to fix?

Comment: @L'Esperanza you need to root your device, otherwise it won't work. check the first sentence.

Comment: This is temporary. If you restart the device which you configured its MTU setting, the setting changes to default (e.g. 1500 for me). There would be a way to automatically run the ifconfig command every time a specific device restarts or to set something like Cron jobs. Or, is there any way to make the MTU values fixed?

Comment: @PauloFidalgo Change "To change MTU settings you need a to root your phone. Search in foruns how to do it. After that your need to install a terminal emulator and check what is your network interface Run the command:" to "To change MTU settings you need to root your phone. Search in foruns how to do it. After that your need to install a terminal emulator and check what is your network interface Run the command:"