# How to know the MTU size of Android Smartphone

Tags: android, mtu

Any command to know the MTU size of Android?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7847980/1006863

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to change android phone's mtu size?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264344/is-there-a-way-to-change-android-phones-mtu-size)

Comment: Not a duplicate of "is there a way to change android phone's mtu size" - this is just how to get the value, not change it.  They are related however

Answer (score 6):

You should use the [NetworkInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/NetworkInterface.html) class to query and obtain the network interfaces, then call `getMTU()`.

Answer (score 6):

Today, looking into the code of netcfg I saw that the configuration of the interfaces is located into /sys/class/net.. and then I thought of you! (I read your question yesterday)

If you have root access, open a terminal and run

```
cat /sys/class/net/<interface>/mtu
```

Answer (score 5):

### Methods to know the MTU size of Android:

1. from [terminal](https://termux.com/): `ifconfig $DEVICE | egrep addr\|MTU`
2. through [Android Debug Bridge (adb)](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb):

   - `adb shell netcfg | grep UP` to find the desired address and
   - `adb shell ip addr show rmnet0` in case of `rmnet0` or
   - `adb shell cat /sys/class/net/rmnet0/mtu` in case of `rmnet0` (as described by @patedit)

Answer (score 4):

**Without ROOTING** your phone, you may use a ping command from a Windows/Mac/Unix system. Though, the syntax of `ping`-options is very different for different OS.

### For Windows

try this:

```
ping /l 1473 /f 10.68.34.75
```

> *`/l <Size>` — Specifies the length, in bytes, of the Data field in the echo Request messages sent. The default is 32.*
>
> *`/f` — Specifies that echo Request messages are sent with the Do not Fragment flag in the IP header set to 1 (available on IPv4 only).*

Adjust the payload using the `-l` command-line option. When you reach the higher limit, you will see this message and you will find the MTU size :

```
> The packet needs to be fragmented but DF set.
```

More details: https://kb.netgear.com/19863/Ping-Test-to-determine-Optimal-MTU-Size-on-Router

Comment: You will find others tips on http://delog.wordpress.com/2013/09/07/using-ping-to-determine-mtu-size/

Comment: after 6 years the link became broken. here is the new one: https://kb.netgear.com/19863/Ping-Test-to-determine-Optimal-MTU-Size-on-Router

Answer (score 1):

1480, I believe, but you can check by using `ifconfig $DEVICE` with a rooted device, and checking the MTU there.

Comment: I believe, that there is a precise technical answer (even several answers). _1480, I believe_ =) bro, it is a technical question, not about beliefs.

Answer (score 1):

For most network access, MTU could be resolved by MTU Discovery. You can use Ping command with different payload size  and don't fragment to find aChrysler value. Good luck

Comment: how the OP could use `ping` to determine the MTU? You didn't provide any instructions

Answer (score 0):

**Without ROOTING** your phone, you may use a ping command from a Windows/Mac/Unix system. Though, the syntax of `ping`-options is very different for different OS.

### From most Unix/Linux/Mac systems (Without ROOTING the phone)

You might share the internet connection from your phone, and then from any PC connected to your android-phone run `ping` commands:

```sh
ping www.yahoo.com -s 1413 -M do
```

> **man ping** says:
>
> *`-s <packetsize>` — Specifies the number of data bytes to be sent. The default is 56, which translates into 64 ICMP data bytes when combined with the 8 bytes of ICMP header data.*
>
> *`-M <pmtudisc_opt>` — Select  Path  MTU Discovery strategy. `<pmtudisc_option>` may be either `do` (prohibit fragmentation, even local one), `want` (do PMTU discovery, fragment locally when packet size is large), or `dont` (do not set **DF** flag).*

Adjust the payload using the `-s` command-line option (for example: *1200, 1300, 1400, 1500, 1450, 1425, 1440, ...*). When you reach the higher limit, you will see a message like this and you will find the MTU size :

```
> From 192.168.1.1 icmp_seq=1 Frag needed and DF set (mtu = 1500)
ping: local error: Message too long, mtu=1500
```

<sub>My answer is based on this one for windows: [answer #25165641](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25165641/1115187)</sub>